# Python2 SQLite module with an ICU extension support (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, unicode, icu

I'm trying to achieve to be able to have unicode support using LIKE operator with my sqlite database. This normally does not work as unicode is not natively supported. ICU extensions for sqlite should enable it.

I am using ActivePython 2.7.10 on Windows 7 x64.

Is it possible to get it working on this setup?

Related: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.web2py/2159